# Why do the 9V batteries immediately deplete on connecting to this circuit?

Tags: batteries, circuit-analysis, 555

My son put together this railroad flasher circuit on a breadboard.

[image: railroad flasher]

He (and I) tried 3 brand-new 9V batteries. On connecting them to the circuit, the batteries immediately deplete/discharge (terminal voltage before connecting is ~9V, and after connecting to this circuit, is ~6V).

I've checked the breadboard wiring several times to see if it matches the circuit, and I could find nothing wrong. Only thing which I am unsure about is the electrolytic capacitor that is a 10uF one, rated at 50VDC. Could that be the problem ? The resistance values are all as per circuit (1/4W ones), and the LEDs are connected correctly. Anything wrong with the circuit ?

***Edit:***
Note that there was indeed a "short". Correct that, but still no fun, no railroad lights. Breadboard wiring picture -

[image]

***Edit#2:***

Thanks for highlighting several mistakes. Here's a Fritzing breadboard view. Hopefully right this time.
[image]

Comment: Looks OK. 10 V capacitor rating is a minimum so your 50 V one is fine. Photo of your setup? We're looking for a short circuit. Make sure you understand which way the strips are running on your breadboard.

Comment: @transistor, thanks. There was indeed a short. I fixed that, but still no railroad lights for us. Added the breadboard picture.

Comment: You are using the "power rails" at bottom BOTH as a means of connecting the cap and of distributing power. Pins 2 & 6 should not connect to the power rails but use wire links and cap orange wire should NOT go to power rals but connect to 2 & 6 with wire links. | Powerrails MUST only be used for power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your breadboard circuit has pins 2, 4, 6, 8, and red LED all connected together. I can't see if Cap +ve is connected to the orange wire. If it is then that's merrily in the circuit too.

I think you don't realise that the edge strips (top and bottom of your photo) run the full length of the breadboard. Normally we use one on each side for ground and the other for V+ as these are used in multiple places on a typical circuit.

Note that the 555 pins are numbered anti-clockwise from pin 1. Pin 2 is beside 1 and not across from it.

Comment: Also, the 47k resistor is connected to pin 3 instead of pin 2.

Comment: Very embarassing... yes, many silly mistakes. Here is the (hopefully) corrected [breadboard layout drawn in fritzing](http://i.imgur.com/yZ7C2ig.png).

Comment: It's OK. You're anonymous here we've all done it. Please accept the answer if you think it was the right one.