# Why does the Green LED stay lit and Red LED stay off in this 555 circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, 555

This extends my [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/205847/why-do-the-9v-batteries-immediately-deplete-on-connecting-to-this-circuit) involving same circuit, information replicated here for convenience and independence of this question.

The following circuit schematic:

[image]

Has been connected as shown here:

[image]

However, on connecting it to the power source (now a 12VDC lead-acid battery, with unloaded terminal voltage as bit over 13VDC, from a robotics kit), I see that only the green LED is glowing (permanently lit), and red LED is unlit. The expected behaviour is both flashing alternately (aka Railroad crossing lights). What all could be wrong here ?

Comment: Both your LEDs in the schematic are marked 'red', rather than one red and one green; Also, which specific version of the 555 are you using?

Comment: Oops, while schematic does indeed say red LED for both, I've just used a combination of red and green in the breadboard layout diagram. As per the schematic, the lower LED glows steady, while upper LED remains unlit. It is NE555 (not the low-voltage type).

Comment: Your schematic is a bit unusual as it does not use the discharge pin (pin 7). I'm unsure how the 555 likes this, I never tried this. Theoretically it should work though. The green led is the one to ground right ? Then the output is high and the 47k resistor must charge the 10uF cap. Get your multimeter and measure this ! NB, also place a 10 uF decoupling cap across the supply rails just to be sure (it is good practice to have this).

Comment: Like [this](http://www.sentex.ca/~mec1995/circ/555test.gif) schematic ?

Comment: Yes exactly, that looks more like the standard way to use a 555.

Comment: @FakeMoustache: Connecting the timing resistor to the output is an easy way to get a 50% duty cycle waveform; it's much simpler than using steering diodes, for example. That isn't the problem.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes I understood that and I agree that it should just work. I would not dare to say that that is not the problem as I have not tried it myself. Sometimes if things don't work you just have to go back to the standard solution. If that also doesn't work then for sure something else is wrong/broken. I could find no other reason why this circuit is not behaving like it should but if you can please point it out.

Comment: Schematic fixed led color @PeterSmith

Comment: You got the circuit working on 9 V after answers received in your previous question. What changed between 9 V and 12 V. It seems as though you've let the smoke out of the 555. Do you have another to try again on 9 V?

Comment: Circuit hadn't worked as expected, but I had found the key mistakes in wiring the circuit on breadboard and the explanation of why battery depleted, I accepted it since I got right pointers. Since the previous question was about why 9V battery immediately depleted, and I've been told in past by moderators to open new question, that's what I did here.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit itself is fine as long as there's enough headroom for the output to swing between 1/3 and 2/3 Vcc, and that's not a problem with a 12 volt supply and little LED loads.

According to LTspice, the circuit should work, so the only things I can think of are that maybe your wiring is different from what you've shown or you've got a bad 555.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your circuit is actually built on the breadboard as shown, you have a breadboard problem.

The long supply rails (two along the top, two along the bottom) are physically split in the middle.

Either place jumpers across the breaks in those rails or move all of the circuit to one side of the breadboard.